# How to get object value for array

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I am new in php and am trying to read **text** and **description** from twitter api. My array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created_at] => Thu Oct 03 14:50:55 +0000 2013
            [id] => 3.85778998506E+17
            [id_str] => 385778998506033154
            [text] => We tested live-tweeting with @MLB to see if teams could boost follower engagement and their Twitter audience: https://t.co/XPhHmVDNxJ
            [source] => TweetDeck
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [user] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 783214
                    [id_str] => 783214
                    [name] => Twitter
                    [screen_name] => twitter
                    [location] => San Francisco, CA
                    [description] => Your official source for news, updates and tips from Twitter, Inc.
                    [url] => http://t.co/5iRhy7wTgu
                    [entities] => stdClass Object
```

I tried to read like this way but cant print anything `echo $tweets->text;`

Comment: If $tweets is an array, shouldn't it be $tweets[0]->text;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $tweets[0]->text;
echo $tweets[0]->user->description;
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an outer array containing the object.  Array access is done via brackets, so you can access the zeroth element via `$tweets[0]`.  Now that you have the object, you can access its properties.  All together this would be `$tweets[0]->text`.  To get user values you would use `$tweets[0]->user->description`, for example.

If there were multiple tweets returned, you could use `$tweets[1]`, etc. to access other tweet values.  You can also iterate over these.

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet->text;
}
```